# Add DropDownButton functionality to marker onTap in Google Maps - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to add a drop down with list of strings to the onTap callback of a Google Maps Marker in Flutter.

I have a service that returns a single Marker which I add to the Map. Here is the MarkerService class that returns a single marker:

```
class MarkerService {
  Marker createMarkerFromPlace(Place place) {
    var markerId = place.name;
    const List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
    String dropdownValue = list.first;

    return Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(markerId),
      draggable: false,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: place.name, snippet: place.vicinity),
      position:
          LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng),
      onTap: () {
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          elevation: 16,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            // This is called when the user selects an item.
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = value!;
            });
          },
          items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Naturally, I get an error on the setState() inside the onChanged:

```
The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'MarkerService'.
```

From what I understand, the method setState() belongs to a class that extends the State super class.

Any ideas on how to add a drop down menu functionality when I tap on the marker? All the tutorials online regarding DropDownButton in Flutter involve creating a different StatefulWidget.

Comment: what is the error?

Also it looks like you are just using a widget as a statement in a function rather than in a buld tree.

Comment: I am extremely new to Flutter. How can I include the DropdownButton widget in a build tree? Thanks! @MindStudio.

Comment: A Widget is not a function that you can execute in another function like onTap.
A Widget is an Instance of a Widget class or subclass that needs to be returned inside the build function of another widget. 

The build function defines the layout of your app. If you need to show parts of the UI conditionally (like the dropdownbutton) you need to wrap it in a Widget that can conditionally enable or switch its child widget. 

```dart
Visibility(visible: isVisible, child: ChildWidget()
),
```

Or alternatively a `Builder()` Widget that returns different Widgets based on if statements.